# Angular2 Material Radio Button Displaying inc

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am using Angular2 Material and I am having issues with the radio dots which are not inside the outer circle.

I am using Angular 4 and the latest version of Angular Material @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3.

[image: Angular Material Design Radio Buttons]

Radio button code

```
        <md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="align">
         <md-radio-button class="example-margin" value="start">Start</md-radio-button>
         <md-radio-button class="example-margin" value="end">End</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
```

Comment: Did you import one of the prebuilt themes or made your own? Did you install `@angular/animations`? Make sure that you import `BrowserAnimatonsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations`!

Comment: No I didnt import the pre-built theme? I didnt see that referenced in the documentation. Do you have an example or link to the documentation?

Comment: Here are the [docs on theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)